# How to enable warning message in printf wrong data format

Tags: c++

My program crash when one of my debug message print bool variable with %s.
For example,

```
bool b_test=false;  
printf("b_test=%s\n",b_test);
```

I am wondering if there is any warning message to check the wrong data format.
After searching the web for a while, I find **-Wall** and **-Wformat** could print some warning message but no warning message for print bool with %s.

Is there gcc setting to print the warning message for print wrong data format?

Thanks a lot.

**Update**

Thanks for all of your reply.

Here is I find both "-Wformat" and "-Wall" will enable warning message. The problem is my colleague also adds another "-Wno-format" in Makefile.

I am using gcc 4.3.3.

Many thanks again.

Comment: Both GCC and Clang should give a warning about that. The warning option is `-Wformat`, and it's enabled by `-Wall`.

Comment: i think -Wall will print this warnings also

Comment: Your example gives me this error message with gcc and clang: `warning: format specifies type 'char *' but the argument has type 'bool' [-Wformat]`. Are you sure you have `#include <cstdio>` and have enabled warnings ?

Comment: `bool` is not **C** (but C++).

Comment: Are you actually writing C (and compiling with gcc), where `bool` is some typedef or macro? Or C++ (with g++)? Because all my local g++ versions catch it, but if you're really working in C, whatever `bool` expands to will make a difference.

Comment: @Jarod42 C supports `bool` (or more precisely `_Bool`) since C11.

Comment: @YuHao The fragment in question has `bool`, not `_Bool`. C supports `_Bool`, not `bool`.

Comment: @n.m. `bool` is defined if `bool.h` is included. My point is, it's a little early to say this is not valid C code. It's like saying `size_t` is not in C.